# How to copy a database using python urllib2 without getting an Error 500?

Tags: python

I would like to copy on my computer a database which is hosted on a [website](http://archive.unctad.org/iia-dbcases/cases.aspx).

I have tried to use python urllib2 and to make a loop to open each link and write a file with the page content. It works perfectly for the first hundred links approximately, and then I get an Error 500 and it seems that the website is also down (runtime error).

Is it due to a security mechanism in the database ? Is there a trick to avoid it ?

Thanks!

Comment: ERROR 500: Internal Server Error. Most likely this is due to an application error on the server, e.g. program crashing. The link you've provided fails with this error. Unless you know the internals of the remote application, you will have little chance of working around it. You'll need to talk to the server's administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I also get an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error). So I don't think this is a security mechanism, but probably a real server error.

Maybe your crawler "clicked" on a link that made the server crashing? Of course, the server error could also be totally independent from your crawling efforts.

Anyway, if the problem persists, it might be worth contacting the owner of the database using the contact details given here: http://archive.unctad.org/iia-dbcases/